# Lines vary at certain scale using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

The lines shown in the pictures start to shift in form from a certain scale onwards (Look at the corners of the polygon). Meaning, that when I'm at a higher scale the line stays the same just as it should do. From this certain scale onwards (or Zooming) it does this altering/shifting thing. As the line units in the symbology are "map units" already, I don't know what fixes this problem.

I want the lines to stay exactly as i draw them no matter at which scale I'm at.

[image: First Zoom]

[image: Second Zoom]

[image: Third Zoom]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the 'Align dash pattern to line length' and 'Tweak dash pattern at sharp corners' options in the polygon symbology settings:

[image]

That way you'll always get a continuous line around sharp corners.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That solved the problem :-) Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hallensis [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)