# PDF Export varies from display in layout view using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, print-composer, pdf

As in [QGIS - Lines vary at a certain scale](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/477706), the problem was solved in the map and layout view, but when I created a PDF, this happened:

As you can see, the edges in the layout view are as sharp as they should be

[image]

But when creating a PDf, it looks like this
[image]

I already tried different export options but no change.

Does anyone know what's causing the problem?

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue, it seems like it's a bug with rendering vectors in PDF. I don't know if it's a technical limitation of the PDF format. It works fine if exporting as .jpg/.png or exporting to .pdf using Export as raster. Maybe you can file a bug on the QGIS github for anyone to sort out if it is a qgis thing or an upstream issue.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how do i export to .pdf using export as raster?

Comment: In the Print Layout window go to the Layout tab (if you don't see it go to the top toolbar, View > Panels > Layout). Under Layout go to Export Settings > Print as raster